# How can i web scrape data outside of div tags

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Im having trouble webscraping a value from https://next-episode.net/star-trek-picard. Im looking to pull the season number from the "Previous__episode" tag ID. The number seems to be in between 2  tags and I cant seem to find a way to reference it. Ive previously been pulling all of the inner text of the previous_episode tag and using regex functions to isolate the values that I want  giving me the following

Previous Episode

Name:Broken Pieces

Date:

Thu Mar 12, 2020

Season:

1

Episode:8

Summary:Episode Summary

(the above has no lines in between them in excel. The formatting in the question box is placing them all on one line for some reason)

Before tonight the number 1 was in the same line as "Season:" allowing my regex function to work.
Or possibly a regex patter to allow me to get the 1 on the next line after "season:"

```
Dim XML_05 As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTML_05 As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

XML_05.Open "GET", Cells(Row, NextEpisodeURL).Value, False
XML_05.send
HTML_05.body.innerHTML = XML_05.responseText


Dim NETC_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim NET_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim REC_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim CEC_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim CE_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim REO_05 As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim MO_05 As Object
Dim SN_05() As String
Dim ENA_05() As String
Dim EN_05() As String
Dim LatestEpisodeName As String



Set NET_05 = HTML_05.getElementById("previous_episode")
Set REO_05 = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    REO_05.Global = True
    REO_05.IgnoreCase = True


REO_05.Pattern = "(Name:(.*))"
    Set MO_05 = REO_05.Execute(NET_05.innerText)
        Debug.Print MO_05.Count
        Debug.Print MO_05(0).Value
            ENA_05 = Split(MO_05(0), ":")
        Debug.Print ENA_05(1)
        LatestEpisodeName = ENA_05(1)


REO_05.Pattern = "(Episode:([0-9]*))"
    Set MO_05 = REO_05.Execute(NET_05.innerText)
        Debug.Print MO_05.Count
        Debug.Print MO_05(0).Value
            EN_05 = Split(MO_05(0), ":")
        Debug.Print EN_05(1)
        Cells(Row, EpisodeNet).Value = EN_05(1)


REO_05.Pattern = "(Season:\s+([0-9]*))"
    Set MO_05 = REO_05.Execute(NET_05.innerText)
        Debug.Print MO_05.Count
        Debug.Print MO_05(5).Value
            SN_05 = Split(MO_05(0), ":")
        Debug.Print SN_05(1)
        Trim (SN_05(1))
        Cells(Row, SeasonNet).Value = SN_05(1)



Set NETC_05 = HTML_05.getElementById("next_episode").Children
    Cells(Row, CountDown).Value = NETC_05(5).innerText
    Debug.Print NETC_05(5).innerText
```

Comment: What's the exact issue? Sounds like you'd need to just update your regex to account for the possible variations in what you want to scrape.

Comment: Did you try the script I've pasted below @LIRAHARA?

Comment: Not yet. Have only just seen this now. Yeah Ive been thinking of ways to update the regex but couldnt figure out the correct pattern.

Comment: Hey SIM, It worked but there seems to be extra white space in there too. It increases the height of my cell like its wrapping text. Ive tried a few things to get rid of this like using the trim function but have not been able to. I downloaded the html into a plain text file and there seems to be a heap of white space in there too which I think is what it is picking up on. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Josh, So the exact issue is the website changed and what would normally be printed out inthe inner text would be "Season:x" and I had set up my regex to give me whatever was after the "Season:" part. But now the inner text shows that the number is on the line under the "Season:". I cant figure out a way to get the code to pick that up. I tried a bunch of things yesterday but nothing worked. I even found where I tried what SIM showed me. The issue with that is there seems to be a bunch of white space that regex picks up also causing excel to not see it as a number.

Comment: I have my table set up so that it pads the digit i scrape with 2 0s and when i use the below pattern the white space seems to mess with it only showing the single number unless I go into the cell and delete the unknown part. Then every thing adjusts correctly. Ive tried a couple o things like the trim function but havent been able to get it to work properly.

Comment: just identified it to be a line break at the beginning of string. Just need to figure out how to get rid of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Const Url$ = "https://next-episode.net/star-trek-picard"
    Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument, post As Object
    Dim rxp As New RegExp, R&

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set post = HTML.getElementById("previous_episode")

    With rxp
        .pattern = "(Name:(.*))"
        If .Execute(post.innerText).Count > 0 Then
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .Execute(post.innerText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        .pattern = "(Season:\s+([0-9]*))"
        If .Execute(post.innerText).Count > 0 Then
            CleanString = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Execute(post.innerText)(0).SubMatches(0))
            SeasonNumber = Split(CleanString, ":")
            Cells(R, 2) = SeasonNumber(1)
        End If

        .pattern = "(Episode:([0-9]*))"
        If .Execute(post.innerText).Count > 0 Then
            Cells(R, 3) = .Execute(post.innerText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is something that might help you get the required fields you wish to grab:

```
Sub FetchData()
    Const Url$ = "https://next-episode.net/star-trek-picard"
    Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument, post As Object
    Dim rxp As New RegExp, R&

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set post = HTML.getElementById("previous_episode")

    With rxp
        .pattern = "(Name:(.*))"
        If .Execute(post.innerText).Count > 0 Then
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .Execute(post.innerText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        .pattern = "(Season:\s*([0-9]*))"
        If .Execute(post.innerText).Count > 0 Then
            Cells(R, 2) = .Execute(post.innerText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        .pattern = "(Episode:([0-9]*))"
        If .Execute(post.innerText).Count > 0 Then
            Cells(R, 3) = .Execute(post.innerText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey SIM, Yeah that works, but not exactly what I was trying to do. The output for that season number is "season:"and the number on the next line. I found that your regex pattern works and below I placed some code to remove the line break. This essentially changes it back to what ive been running with for the last 6 months and my code works after that. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is cleaner and faster to use the DOM to your advantage. The nodes you want are `NextSiblings` to the items matched by the nice and fast css selector `#previous_episode  .subheadline`. You get a returned nodeList which are the left hand side elements e.g. "Name", "Date" etc... Simply, navigate with `NextSibling` to jump to the right hand side elements e.g. "Et in Arcadia Ego, Part 1".

The returned `nodeList` starts at 0 and you can index in to get individual items. Note that the second item you want is a `textNode` and therefore you must use a `NodeValue` property rather than `innerText`.

This is faster and mpre correct in terms of dealing with HTML parsing.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetPriorEpisodeInfp()
    Const URL = "https://next-episode.net/star-trek-picard"
    Dim html As New mshtml.HTMLDocument, previousEpisodeItems As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set previousEpisodeItems = html.querySelectorAll("#previous_episode  .subheadline")

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = previousEpisodeItems.item(0).NextSibling.innerText
        .Cells(1, 2) = previousEpisodeItems.item(2).NextSibling.NodeValue 'textNode
        .Cells(1, 3) = previousEpisodeItems.item(3).NextSibling.innerText
    End With
End Sub
```